# download gpt4all-falcon-q4_0.gguf

Tags: vscode-extensions, large-language-model, falcon, gpt4all

I downloaded the `gpt4all-falcon-q4_0.gguf` locally on my device to make a local app on `VScode`.

```
from gpt4all import GPT4All
model = GPT4All(r"C:\Users\Issa\Desktop\GRADproject\Lib\site-packages\Gpt4all_Modules\gpt4all-falcon-q4_0.gguf")
```

I'm encountering this error:

```
Value Error: Invalid model directory: gpt4all-falcon-q4_0.gguf
```

Although, I'm sure that the directory is correct.

I'm using windows 11 and python 3.5

Although, on Google Colab, it worked normally, I think then problem is either in the Python version or I'm missing a `Vscode` extension that I should add or download a certain next to it module.